# Issues numerically integrating a multivariable function WRT a single variable in Julia (using hcubature)

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

`hcubature` keeps returning zeros for me.

I have a multivariable function that I would like to integrate with respect to one variable. As a test, I use `quadgk`, which can only be used for 1 variable (hardcoding the other variables), and it works.

However, when using `hcubature` my integration returns zeros.

here is my minimal non-working example

```
psi_1D_PIB(x, n, L) = sqrt(2/L) * sin(n * π * x / L)
psi_conj_PIB(x, n, L) = conj(psi_1D_PIB(x, n, L)) * psi_1D_PIB(x, n, L) 
psi_conj_PIB(v) = psi_conj_PIB(v...)  # as per hcubature documentation, send an array
println(hcubature(psi_conj_PIB, (1.,1, 5.), (5.,1,5.))) # integrate x from 1 to 5, n from 1 to 1, and L from 5 to 5.
                                                        # first tuple is LH bounds, second is RH integration bounds
```

output is `0.0, 0.0)` The missing left hand parenthesis does not appear to be a typo

Using `guadgk` to calculate this essentially single variable integral,

```
psi_1D_PIB(x) = sqrt(2/5) * sin(1 * π * x / 5)
psi_conj_PIB(x) = conj(psi_1D_PIB(x)) * psi_1D_PIB(x) 
println(quadgk(psi_conj_PIB, 1., 5.))
```

output is `(0.9513653457281316, 2.5028679129235343e-10)`

For additional information, this is the function being integrated
[image]

Comment: Pretty sure `hcubature` is fine, and my calculus past midnight is shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use:

```
julia> println(hcubature(x->psi_conj_PIB(first(x),1,5),[1.],[5.]))
(0.9513653457281317, 2.5028645822544604e-10)
```

You have a function **f(x,y,z)** and want to compute its integral over the interval x in [1,5] for given values y=1, z=5.

The right way to do that is to restrict your **R^3** function **f(x,y,z)** to a **R** function: **x->g(x) = f(x,1,5)** and to compute the integral of **g** over the [1,5] interval. In Julia this is written

```
x->psi_conj_PIB(first(x),1,5)
```

**Note:** here you must use an extra `first(x)` to get a scalar from the **x** vector of dimension one, because your **R^n** domain of integration is in fact a simple **R** domain defined by lower bound = [1], upper bound = [5].

**Note 2:** this is not equivalent to compute an integral over the region **(x,y,z)** in **[1,5]x[1,1]x[5,5]**. This **R^3** region has a null "volume": (5-1)x(1-1)x(5-5) = 4x0x0 = 0, thus whatever the function you want to integrate its integral over this region is null. This is what you experimented in your example.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion last night :)

Comment: `hcubature(x->conj(psi_1D_PIB(first(x), n, L)) * psi_1D_PIB(first(x), n, L), [1.], [5.]))` works fine and is tidyish looking